# How Can I Convert Form Navigation Link to a Button?

Tags: php, button, hyperlink, navigation

I have the following link

```
 <a href='#'  class='prev-tab mover' rel='\" + prev + \"'>« Previous</a>
```

that I am trying to turn into a button that will match up with the site's CSS.  There has to be a simple fix for this, what is it?

As a side note, this bit of code was pulled from a php script.

Comment: Maybe using the <button> tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can nest a button inside an anchor tag, like this:

```
<a href='#'  class='prev-tab mover' rel='\" + prev + \"'><button>« Previous</button></a>
```

You'll still want to use css to make it look good, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use css to make it look like a button.

```
<style>a.prev-tab{background:#333;padding:5px;border:1px solid #000}</style>
```